# How to call dropdown value from one java class(page) to another TestNG class(test) in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dropdown

I want to select and store a dropdown value in one element in a page(java class) and call it from different class.

EX : i am doing like this for all other fields

```
public class Home_page {

    private static WebElement element = null;

    public static WebElement txtbox_FirstName(WebDriver driver) {
        element = driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_g"));
        return element;
    }
}

public class Action_createAccount {

    private static WebDriver driver = null;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E://chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");


    Home_page.txtbox_FirstName(driver).sendKeys("Anu");
   }
}
```

and this is working perfectly. I am not able to write code for drop down to work in the same way. Please help

Comment: Can you show us the `drop down` code trials?

Comment: I really dont know how to achieve this so was trying like this.
public static WebElement drpdwn_BirthYear(WebDriver driver) {
element = driver.findElement(By.id("year"));

  Select dropdown = new Select(drpdwn_BirthYear(driver));

  dropdown.selectByVisibleText("1991");;

  return element;
}

Comment: So i had to give like this directly in class page  : 

Select drpdwn_BirthDate = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("day")));
 drpdwn_BirthDate.selectByIndex(3);

Comment: Please check my answer, it may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select birth day, the sample code is here. it may help you.

```
public class Home_page {
    private static WebElement element = null;

    public static WebElement txtbox_FirstName(WebDriver driver) {
        element = driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_g"));
        return element;
    }
    Public static WebElement dropdown_BirthDay_Day(WebDriver driver){
        element = driver.findElement(By.id("day"));
        return element;
    }
    Public static WebElement dropdown_BirthDay_Month(WebDriver driver){
        element = driver.findElement(By.id("month"));
        return element;
    }Public static WebElement dropdown_BirthDay_Year(WebDriver driver){
        element = driver.findElement(By.id("year"));
        return element;
    }

}

public class Action_createAccount {

    private static WebDriver driver = null;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E://chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");


        Home_page.txtbox_FirstName(driver).sendKeys("Anu");
        new Select(Home_page.dropdown_BirthDay_Day(driver)).selectByVisibleText("16");
        new Select(Home_page.dropdown_BirthDay_Month(driver)).selectByVisibleText("Nov");
        new Select(Home_page.dropdown_BirthDay_Year(driver)).selectByVisibleText("1990");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Murthi it really worked in no time.. I was struggling a lot to fix this :)